# parsing ReactJS with pretty url

Tags: reactjs, query-string

I have the following URL:

```
http://hostname/RoutingTool/Page/1
```

1. **RoutingTool** is the component
2. **Page** is the element to render
3. **1** is the id to load from db

I am using it to retrieve the values from the query string.

```
 const name = new URLSearchParams(window.location.href).values();
```

but it fails to read the values as it is expecting (returns undefined or null)

```
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams("key1=value1&key2=value2");
```

what am I doing wrong or what am I overlooking?

Comment: have you considere checking the `useParams` hooks ?

Comment: yes, Same thing.